# What is the cost of accessing shared memory on a NUMA machine?

Tags: windows, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I have a collection of EXEs running on Windows Server 2019.  They use shared memory (Memory mapped files) to share some state.  I am on a NUMA machine and the EXEs get scheduled on different cores (physical CPUs).  Hence the the memory being shared must be accessed by the bus between the cores.  So my question is this: Is there a performance overhead in this sort of access when the data is not changing?

To amplify the point, assume the sender EXE only touches that shared memory very rarely.  Does that mean the client EXEs on other cores will always have to pull data through the inter-CPU bus, or does it only happen when the original contents changes?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: *As far as I know*, in the current systems if the data doesn’t stay in the CPU cache it will every time need to be retrieved through the interchange. It’s not cloned in any way to the other NUMA area. If it’s not changed and the CPU keeps it in cache then it doesn’t need to retrieve it again and again.